# Extracting Multiple Numerical Values from Text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2017

```
048(70F-Y),045(DDI-Y),454(CMDE-Y)
```

I have the above data in a column field, I need to extract each number before the, so in the above example I would want to see 048, 045, 454.

Note the data in the field will change in each record in the above you have 3 sets of numbers. Sometimes you may have just one set or 6 sets. I just need to capture all sets of numbers that are to the left of the `(`.

Ideally I would want the results to show in a new column like below. I have tried a few things and gotten no where any help would be greatly appreciate.

I would expect the result to look like the below:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------+
| EventId  |            PAEditTypes            |     Edits     |
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------+
|  6929107 | 082(SPA-Y),177(QL-Y)              |      082, 177 |
| 26534980 | 048(70F-Y),045(DDI-Y),454(CMDE-Y) | 045, 048, 454 |
+----------+-----------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I would recommend function or a loop for this case

Comment: I would prefer to use a loop and that is what I am trying to develop but not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Use `string_split()` on commas. Then extract everything before initial paren using `left()` and `charindex()`. Recombine with `listagg()` Is order important?

Comment: I used the string_spilit but not sure how to do the left and charindex() piece you recommend.

Comment: SELECT 
 evt.EventId
 , s.value 
 FROM [PBM_Ops_Reporting].[Pahub].[Events] AS EVT 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(evt.[PAEditTypes], '(') S

Comment: EventId value
6929107 082
6929107 SPA-Y),177
6929107 QL-Y)
26534980 048
26534980 70F-Y),045
26534980 DDI-Y),454
26534980 CMDE-Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired output with the following step:

1. use `string_split` with `cross apply` to isolate each item
2. use `left` to get only the first part of each item together with `CHARINDEX` to know where you have to stop
3. use `STRING_AGG` to build the final result, adding `WITHIN GROUP` clause to enforce ordering (if ordering is not important just remove `WITHIN GROUP` clause)

This is a TSQL sample that should work:

```
declare @tmp table ( EventId  varchar(50), PAEditTypes varchar(200) )

insert into @tmp values
     ('6929107' ,'082(SPA-Y),177(QL-Y)'             ) 
    ,('26534980','048(70F-Y),045(DDI-Y),454(CMDE-Y)') 

select 
     EventId
   , PAEditTypes
   , STRING_AGG(left(value,CHARINDEX('(',value)-1),', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value ASC) as Edits
from 
    @tmp
        cross apply 
    string_split(PAEditTypes, ',')
group by 
      EventId
    , PAEditTypes
order by
    EventId desc
```

Output:

[image]